# What type of variable it returned by the Time function in VB6

Tags: time, vb6

In VB6, what type of Variable is returned by the `Time` function?

```
Dim x
x = Time
```

I know that by default `x` is a variant, but I want to add `As FooBar` onto the end of this. What type is FooBar?

Thanks

Comment: From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62dhtt92(v=vs.80).aspx) link: "In Visual Basic 6.0, the Date and Time functions return the system date and time in the four-byte Date format." So I believe the answer is "As Date".

Comment: +1 for trying to do it properly :)

Comment: Date values are *8 byte* "double" values under the covers.  In the "Anders Era" there seem to be lots of errors of this sort at Microsoft.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the manual clearly states:

> Returns a Variant (Date) indicating the current system time.

Comment: From memory, the 'date' portion will be `January 0 1900`. Yes, January the zeroth.

Comment: No, you get the "base day" for VT_DATE values, e.g. 1899-12-30 12:43:10

Comment: Who would have thought that Time's could be so interesting! Thanks